# JavaFX 8 - Screen.getVisualBounds() includes the taskbar

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am adding a `Canvas` in a maximized window, and I am setting its height to the height I get from `getVisualBounds()`, but I think a part of the canvas is actually behind the taskbar.

```
double canvasWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() * 0.80;
double canvasHeight = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
canvas = new Canvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
gc.setFill(Color.RED);
gc.fillRect(0, canvasHeight-30, canvasWidth, 30);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, 30);
root.setCenter(canvas);
```

To make it visible I have added a 30px red bar in the top and bottom of the canvas. You can see that in the bottom only a small part of the bar appears because the rest of it is hidden behind the taskbar.

[image: screenshot]

I am using Windows 10. How can I fix this (without hiding the taskbar)? Is there something else I should be using other than `getVisualBounds()`?
Or will I have to figure out the size and position of the taskbar manually? If so, how?

Comment: You didn't take the size of the window's frame into account. The window title is about the same size as the missing part of the `Canvas`.

Comment: @fabian That worked. Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: I don't know what worked. I simply mentioned the source of the issue, not a way to fix it. You can answer your own question btw. You just need to wait some time until you're allowed to accept it...